# How do I directly edit a php file that's included in a block?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-blocks

I have been tasked with changing the code in a block in drupal. When I go to the block (by clicking "configure"), it shows:

```
Block body:
    <?php include('sites/all/contemplates/code-file.php') ?>
```

How do I edit that file `code-file.php` from within the Drupal interface?

Comment: As it is just an included file, you can not edit it from the interface afaik

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly edit executable php files from within your Drupal installation, nor should you or want anyone to be able to. The security implications of uploading executable php files/code to the server via the ui are worrisome.

You should obtain a copy of file, modify it as needed and upload it to your installation via ssh or ftp. Also, using Git makes deployments pretty straightforward.

With all that being said, Drupal core comes with a php filter module that allows you to embed php code that gets executed in text fields. But this isn't considered a good practice anymore either.